# Using a service to request activity updates - how to process Intents

Tags: android, android-activity, service

Have an application that I am refactoring to use a service instead of an IntentService to process Activity updates. Currently using requestActivityUpdates to use a method that collects the intent and sends it to a IntentService based class for processing.

```
ActivityRecognition.ActivityRecognitionApi.requestActivityUpdates(
            mGoogleApiClient,
            DETECTION_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS,
            getActivityDetectionPendingIntent()
    ).setResultCallback(this);
```

AND

```
private PendingIntent getActivityDetectionPendingIntent() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityIntentService.class);
    return PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}
```

Is there a way to process the pendingIntent directly in my service class without passing it off to the IntentService?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PendingIntent.getService()` works for both IntentService and regular Service. Just replace

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityIntentService.class);
```

with

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityService.class);
```

(or whatever the name of your Service is).

Also see the documentation for PendingIntent.getService():

> Retrieve a PendingIntent that will start a service, **like calling Context.startService()**. The start arguments given to the service will come from the extras of the Intent.

The intent that is received by `IntentService.onHandleIntent(Intent intent)` will in a regular Service be received by `onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)`.

Comment: @T.Barrett well now it's documented here :-)